# Ubuntu 16.04, WiFi not working | no Ethernet / can't find driver

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless

so recently I bought myself an **acer switch, tablet/laptop combo** (detachable keyboard). Anywho, it came preloaded with windows 10, so I decided to switch over to a linux distro for more space, and speed.
So I finally buy an otg cable (there is **no usb port ON tablet**, only on the keyboard, but you can't boot through that), and **ubuntu boots smooth on the otg live usb**, no problems.

Before doing this, I kinda figured there would be driver issues. And there is NO Ethernet port, so even more difficult till I get wifi working.

***ALL I NEED IS TO GET THE WIFI WORKING***

*I collected some of my computers wifi information with a script and maybe a few more experienced users could help me.*

[**MY WIFI INFO**](https://pastebin.com/FY5Ytky5)

Thanks guys!

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2335387

Comment: Hi I tried it too on an Acer Aspire Switch ...for the same reason since it is kinda slow^^  no luck with Ubuntu and the wifi I think it doesn't work...

Comment: @chili555 the discussion in your link comes to no conclusion except that it might be a bug but there seems to be no solution to this problem

Comment: @Casey I actually managed somehow to boot and install via the keyboard's USB but some distros other than pure Ubuntu already failed during installation...

Comment: "the discussion in your link comes to no conclusion" Exactly. There is no known way currently to get the wireless working.

Comment: @chilli555 Are you sure? I mean if I connected a USB-to-Ethernet adapter and hooked up wired wifi temporarily, are you sure there are no drivers or no things in my link that show it is a simple problem? Is it just the computer itself?

Comment: @Casey When chili555 says something about WiFi he's usually correct. Also there' s no such thing as "wired wifi"... WiFi is wireless, it's in the name. Cabled connections are usually Ethernet. You can call it by many names but please not "wifi".

Comment: In the link I gave and also in your paste, there is no device showing *at all* that resembles wireless. In the thread, we suspected it might be an SDIO device and looked in the log for sdio to no avail. I don't know how or what to install for something I can't even see. Do you see any further clues here? `dmesg | grep -i sdio`

Comment: @michaelbay sorry haha you're right! My bad, used to calling it wifi around other people.

Comment: @chili555 Yes! I'm away on business at the moment until Sunday evening at the soonest, but it is an Sdio device, I'm quite sure. I found my model and everything else, from within windows, but I can't get back to you on it until Sunday. Also found a form with uncompiled drivers for Bluetooth, wireless, and audio, for my exact models, but couldn't compile / run them. I'll get back very soon! And try your command listed. Thank you so much so far lol this has been so frustrating, and I can tell you're very experienced obviously. Slightly new to Linux interworkings.

Comment: After we see the results of the dmeg, also tell us more about the drivers you have. If the description is lengthy, post it here and give us the link: http://paste.ubuntu.com

Comment: @chili555 hey there! Back home :) anywho, I did the "dmesg | grep -i sdio" as you said, and it gave no results, almost like it wasn't even acknowledged, but proceeding to try it a few different ways, simply "dmesg sido" worked (let me know if you want me to try others).

[RESULTS HERE](http://paste.ubuntu.com/25156345/)

Comment: @chili555 And here's a little info I can give you from windows:

Des: "Realtek RTL8723BS Wireless LAN 802.11n SDIO Network Adapter."      
    
My current driver version is: 3008.33.430.2016.      
Date of driver: 2016-05-31.     
driver files: rtldata.dat, rtwlans.sys, vwifibus.sys (in system 32).

Comment: @chili555 I found a [POST](https://github.com/Manouchehri/vi8/issues/2) on github that seemed promising, so I downloaded the [DRIVER](https://github.com/hadess/rtl8723bs) to test it, but after I did the "make" command (to compile the driver), there were no results to the command. I do not know if this is because I was on a bootable version of linux instead of installed, but I couldn't install the other drivers either (bt and audio are there somewhere), it just didn't work with "make", and "make install".

Comment: This is the one I suggest you try: https://github.com/hadess/rtl8723bs Please explain the exact steps you took. Maybe we can troubleshoot. It should work in a live session; either USB or DVD.

Comment: @chili555 I'll do my best to explain, maybe show you screenshots, hopefully that can help and it may be something simple lol.
1st.) I got the driver zip file on a USB with my second pc, dragged it over to the desktop on my onto ubuntu from the usb, and then extracted it, also on the desktop.
2nd.) I tried to compile / install the driver. So I opened the terminal in the extracted driver folder directory, and ran the commands "make", and then "make install", no new files appeared, nothing seemed to change, wifi device was still not discovered, so I assume it didn't install or didn't work

Comment: @chili555 Here is a screenshot I took after trying the install [IMAGE](https://imagebin.ca/v/3UR56QQfsrE4)

Comment: LOL! Looking at the Makefile, it appears to install the firmware only, although it purports to build a driver. Please try this instead: https://github.com/anthonywong/rtl8723bs

Comment: @chili555 Oh my ahaha, whether the new driver works or not, that's just great. I'm trying it now!! Fingers crossed

Comment: @chili555 So closeeee agh. ** [IMAGE](https://imagebin.ca/v/3UUvWhVvn61C) ** I ran the "make" command, it started compiling correctly, then came to an error about date and time? Lol what? Hope that this may be simple. I couldn't understand much of what it said after.

Comment: Open the Makefile with a text editor and un-comment the line: *#EXTRA_CFLAGS += -Wno-error=date-time # Fix compile error on gcc 4.9 and later* by removing *only* the leading #. Save and close the text editor and try again: make clean and then make and if and only if it 'makes', sudo make install.

Comment: @chili555 Good news and possible bad news lol, it installed :) it only gave a warning but completed making, and then I did the make install [IMAGE1](https://imagebin.ca/v/3UVuhq0fiMQL) , [IMAGE2](https://imagebin.ca/v/3UVv77y8CGU5) . But oddly, it says "no network devices available"? What's this about? [IMAGE3](https://imagebin.ca/v/3UVvwKbNlVdZ) Am I supposed to do something else after installing?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62745/discussion-between-chili555-and-casey).

Comment: Plz halp :') https://xkcd.com/979