# Wifi Drivers Not Working (10ec:8852) But Some Present (No Ethernet)

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, realtek-wireless

I am having some trouble with my new laptop. It appears that the drivers are installed but I A: Cant tell if they are working when I try to load them (via `rtw88_pci` which is different than what I saw [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1352260/wifi-adapter-not-found-realtek-10ec8852-on-ubuntu-21-04) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/937857/ubuntu-16-04-wifi-not-working-no-ethernet-cant-find-driver)) B: Dont know if the proper driver is installed (`modprobe rtw89pci` tells me its not present, but I do see `rtw88_pci` and a bunch of other `.ko` files). Please keep in mind I dont have an ethernet port on this machine

Thank you

Comment: Please add the output of `lspci | grep Network`

Comment: @TD15 `02:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device 8852`

Comment: Can you try the instructions that are in here?:
https://github.com/lwfinger/rtw89

Comment: @TD15 No internet connection

Comment: I think your only hope is to use a non-Ubuntu kernel and use the rtw89 driver

Comment: @TD15 Non-Ubuntu because another distro may have implemented it? Also are you saying to install another OS or live boot or something?

Comment: I think there is a way to use a non Ubuntu kernel on an Ubuntu based distro. I think they are called mainline kernels.

Comment: @TD15 I was not aware that Ubuntu's kernel was different than the standard Linux. Why would swapping the kernel fix it?

Comment: @TD15 If I live booted an OS with a mainline kernel, do you think I could yoink the drivers and copy/paste them onto my Pop instillation?

Comment: Because the rtw89 driver can't compile on Ubuntu kernels, clearly stated in the github instructions.
Read this guide on how to install another kernel: https://www.fossmint.com/ukuu-install-and-upgrade-linux-kernels-in-ubuntu/

Comment: I forgot to say Pop!_OS has a modified Ubuntu kernel, it won't work either.

Comment: @TD15 So what would the next step be? Also is there a way to find if the driver is already present on my computer?

Comment: Your next step should be: install latest mainline kernel following this guide: https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2020/08/mainline-install-latest-kernel-ubuntu-linux-mint/

Follow the github instructions for rtw89 as I sent in the previous Github link. Hopefully it will work.

Comment: @TD15 I did end up making it work, I was able to get the repo onto the computer. If you want to post an answer I will mark it as such. Thank you for your help :)

Comment: You're welcome, can you tell me what exactly worked? Mainline kernel + rtw89 right?